# EditText, adjustPan, ScrollView issue in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview, adjustpan

I have a `EditText` which is enclosed in `ScrollView`, but when the keyboard comes up.

You can NOT scroll down to the fields that are now covered. I have tried adding `adjustSize`, `adjustPan` in the manifest and in the class.

But its not working..

Comment: hi, you able to find any solution

Answer (score 12):

I was suffering from the same issue and I a found solution. So, maybe it will help you.

Please give following attributes to ScrollView tag:

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

And in manifest of your activity to :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: did not work for me. no change whether i added android:isScrollContainer="false" or not

Answer (score 7):

In  your manifest file inside activity tag use

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Answer (score 4):

just struggled for 3 hours to fix this same problem.

What worked for me is to remove "adjustPan" from the windowSoftInputMode in the manifest.

So I went from :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan|stateHidden"
```

to:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

and it fixed everything for me.

I hope this helps anyone else that stumbles upon this too. Funny enough, on my other screens it all still works regardless of the adjustPan.

Answer (score 1):

you just add this line in scrollview **android:isScrollContainer="true"**

Like something this

```
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">
```