# AdjustPan not working in some layouts

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have AdjustPan on all my layouts set as:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">


    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustPan</item>
</style>
```

But there is one layout that contains a couple of static fragments where if I click the textbox inside the fragment, the background image resizes and the views that are aligned to the parents bottom go up.

I tried to set the manifest to:

```
<activity
        android:name=".CaptureVisitActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_capture_visit"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
```

But again, the window is resized.

This is the layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_landscape"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".CaptureVisitActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_capture_visit"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/sv1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/frag_summary"
                    android:name="com.vancert.activities.CaptureVisitActivity$JobSummaryFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_job_summary" />

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/frag_further_work"
                    android:name="com.vancert.activities.CaptureVisitActivity$JobFurtherWorkFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_further_work" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment1"
                android:name="com.vancert.activities.CaptureVisitActivity$JobReportsFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_job_reports" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_job_appliances"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        layout="@layout/layout_footer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the fragment_job_summary is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/summary"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_summary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/engineer_notes_label" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_fast_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_button4"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/fasttext" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_eng_notes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="3" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: use adjustResize instead

Comment: @santalu I've found the answer. It's related to the scrollview. adjustResize wouldn't solve the problem because that's what I'm trying to avoid... resizing the background. But thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im terribly sorry. I just didn't google enough.

Refer to: [EditText, adjustPan, ScrollView issue in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449152/edittext-adjustpan-scrollview-issue-in-android)

It has the answer to this problem.